# How to send API request from inside addEventListener in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener

I have an html file where I created some input fields from where I collect email and password from user. I then pass these values to a javascript file. I am using `addEventListener()` to detect clicking of the login button. Inside `addEventListener()` I call another function which basically sends API request to a backend server using `XMLHttpRequest()`. But it seems like the the request is not being sent to the server. Here is my code:

index.html

```
<html>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <label>Email :</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>Password :</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  <br /><br />
  <button type="submit" id="login">Login</button>
</html>
```

index.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var signin_btn = document.getElementById("login");
  signin_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    validate();
  });
});

function validate() {
  console.log("validate running.");
  var username = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  console.log("username: ", username);

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      auth_token = JSON.parse(this.responseText)["token"];
      localStorage.setItem("auth_token", auth_token);
      console.log("auth from index.js: ", auth_token);
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/userauth/login", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ email: username, password: password }));
  };
}
```

When I run this code, only the `console.log("username: ", username);` part appears in the console. But the `console.log("auth from index.js: ", auth_token);` is not displayed. Seems like the request is not being executed at all. Also no errors are shown in backend as well. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You've put the code that sends the HTTP Request inside the `onreadystatechange` handler, so it is never fired. You want the `open` and `send` method calls to be outside the XHR handler, because right now your click event handler creates an XHR object, assigns it a handler...and does nothing else. You probably meant to do this:

```js
function validate() {
  console.log("validate running.");
  var username = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  console.log("username: ", username);

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      auth_token = JSON.parse(this.responseText)["token"];
      localStorage.setItem("auth_token", auth_token);
      console.log("auth from index.js: ", auth_token);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/userauth/login", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ email: username, password: password }));
}
```

In general, I would recommend using a library like jQuery or the new [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) because doing manual XHRs like this is a pain. But other than this problem your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the request sending lines inside the function, which is a callback function. Change the `validate()` function according to the following code.

```
function validate() {
    console.log("validate running.");
    var username = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    console.log("username: ", username);

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            auth_token = JSON.parse(this.responseText)["token"];
            localStorage.setItem("auth_token", auth_token);
            console.log("auth from index.js: ", auth_token);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/userauth/login", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ email: username, password: password }));
}
```